# how can I export a variable from SSH in jenkins on a remote machine to shell on local one?

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, ssh, devops

my question is this: how can I export a variable from SSH session that is connected to a remote machine to use it on a shell with a local host, all that is on jenkins?
my SSH script is as follows:

```
cd /home/$USER/link
docker-compose -f link.yml up -d #this is a script, in my case I use a docker command, the file exists and is copied in another post
echo the application is available at:
CID=$(docker ps -qf "name=webapp1" |tail -1)
app_ip=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $CID) #to get the ip address of the last container
echo $app_ip:8080
```

I want to use `$app_ip`on the shell, A.K.A on the host machine terminal but I don't know how to proceed, my attempt was to use `ssh -t root@192.168.197.141 env app_ip='$(echo $app_ip)' bash -i` but obviously it needs authentication which I think that it is not possible on jenkins, can you point me to the right direction? thanks

Comment: You have a shell script in a remote Linux host. This script needs an environment variable. Do you want pass this variable from Jenkins?

Comment: I just want to pass a variable to the client machine from the SSH server, or pass the variable to Jenkins so I can use it on a shell script (normal one)

Comment: In the title you said : how can I export a variable **from** SSH in jenkins ... but in the last comment , you say : pass the variable **to** Jenkins.  I will repeat my question in order to understand and help you : You have two machines. One with Jenkins and one with a simple linux script. Your aim is pass one variable **from** Jenkins **to** the script hosted in the linux machine? Is it correct?

Comment: sorry for being confusing, what I want is to pass a variable from the distant SSH server which is connected with SSH to the host, the Jenkins one, or at least passing that variable from SSH to Jenkins so I can use it for another script that involves Testing and stuff that I don't know because they will appear with time

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script called **script.sh**, you can get the input arguments using $1, $2, etc or $@ to get all parameters.

```
echo "Hi, the first argument is $1" 
echo "Hi, all the arguments are: $@"
```

You can pass arguments to it, simply by appending them in the same line :

```
bash script.sh "master" "production"
```

And the result will be:

```
Hi, the first argument is master
Hi, all the arguments are: master production
```

---

## Remote execution using ssh

If your **script.sh** is located in **/devops folder** in a remote machine **108.107.106.105** with user **my_user** , you can execute it and send arguments with this line:

```
ssh -i /tmp/myKey my_user@108.107.106.105 /devops/script.sh "master" "production"
```

Result will be the same.

Comment: sorry for being so rude but that doesn't respond to my question, I have a Jenkins machine that has the SSH agent plugin installed, I have executed some commands through SSH to another machine that has docker installed, meanwhile I have some variables that I must use with another script on the host machine, my question is: can I pass the variables to that Jenkins machine or at least can I pass those variables to Jenkins?

Comment: to better see the problem, I have uploaded a screenshot here https://imgur.com/PuPOqKg